# Unable to add images to python generated plottable table

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, plottable

I would like to make a column of La Liga team logos at the side of a plottable table I created based off of [McKay Johns' YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HVT0lHaIKg). What I am trying to do is grab them from [his github folder](https://github.com/mckayjohns/youtube-videos/tree/main/team_logos) and then add them to the table using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
import datetime
import math
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plottable import ColumnDefinition, Table
from plottable.cmap import normed_cmap
from plottable.plots import image

# Let's make a table look nice :)
la_liga = pd.read_html('https://fbref.com/en/comps/12/La-Liga-Stats', attrs={'id':'results2023-2024121_overall'})[0]

#Grab Club Badges
la_liga['badge'] = la_liga['Squad'].apply(lambda x: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mckayjohns/youtube-videos/main/team_logos/' + str(x).lower().replace(" ", "%20").replace("é", "e").replace("á","a").replace("í","i") + '_logo.png')

la_liga = la_liga[['Rk', 'badge', 'Squad', 'MP', 'W', 'D', 'L',
                   'GF', 'GA', 'GD', 'Pts', 'Pts/MP',
                    'xG', 'xGA', 'xGD']]

#Set color palattes (check out coolor.co)
bg_color = '#FFFFFF'
text_color = '#000000'

row_colors = {
    "top4": "#E1FABC",
    "top6": "#FFFC97",
    "relegation": "#E79A9A",
    "even": "#E2E2E1",
    "odd": "#B3B0B0",
}

plt.rcParams['text.color'] = text_color
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'monospace'

#Create definitions
col_defs = [
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="Rk",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="badge",
        textprops={"ha": "center", "va": "center", 'color': bg_color},
        width=0.5,
        plot_fn=image,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="Squad",
        textprops={"ha": "left", "weight": "bold"},
        width=1.75,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="MP",
        group="Matches Played",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="W",
        group="Matches Played",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="D",
        group="Matches Played",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="L",
        group="Matches Played",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="GF",
        group="Goals",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="GA",
        group="Goals",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="GD",
        group="Goals",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="Pts",
        group="Points",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="Pts/MP",
        group="Points",
        textprops={"ha": "center"},
        width=0.5,
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="xG",
        group="Expected Goals",
        textprops={"ha": "center", "color": "#000000", "weight": "bold", "bbox": {"boxstyle": "circle", "pad": 0.35}},
        cmap=normed_cmap(la_liga["xG"], cmap=matplotlib.cm.PiYG, num_stds=2)
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="xGA",
        group="Expected Goals",
        textprops={"ha": "center", "color": "#000000", "weight": "bold", "bbox": {"boxstyle": "circle", "pad": 0.35}},
        cmap=normed_cmap(la_liga["xGA"], cmap=matplotlib.cm.PiYG_r, num_stds=2)
    ),
    ColumnDefinition(
        name="xGD",
        group="Expected Goals",
        textprops={"ha": "center", "color": "#000000", "weight": "bold", "bbox": {"boxstyle": "circle", "pad": 0.35}},
        cmap=normed_cmap(la_liga["xGD"], cmap=matplotlib.cm.PiYG, num_stds=2)
    ),
]
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = [20, 22])
fig.set_facecolor(bg_color)
ax.set_facecolor(bg_color)

table = Table(
    la_liga,
    column_definitions=col_defs,
    index_col="Rk",
    row_dividers=True,
    row_divider_kw={"linewidth": 1, "linestyle": (0, (1, 5))},
    footer_divider=True,
    textprops={"fontsize": 14},
    col_label_divider_kw={"linewidth": 1, "linestyle": "-"},
    column_border_kw={"linewidth": .5, "linestyle": "-"},
    ax=ax,
).autoset_fontcolors(colnames=["xG", "xGA", "xGD"])

for idx in [0, 1, 2, 3]:
  table.rows[idx].set_facecolor(row_colors['top4'])

for idx in [4, 5]:
  table.rows[idx].set_facecolor(row_colors['top6'])

for idx in [17, 18, 19]:
  table.rows[idx].set_facecolor(row_colors['relegation'])

# fig.savefig('/Uer/benlutz/Desktop/laliga_table.png',
#             facecolor = ax.get_facecolor(),
#             dpi = 200,
#             bbox_inches = 'tight')
fig.show
```

However, this is leading to the following error message:

```
ValueError: Please open the URL for reading and pass the result to Pillow, e.g. with ``np.array(PIL.Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url)))``.
```

Any suggestions as to how to showcase them would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.